# How to add button in a row of JTable in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have made one swing GUI which have JTable with some rows and Columns.How should I add a button to row in a JTable ?

Answer (score 37):

You don't add it to a row - you add it to the cell. [This tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) describes what you need.

Comment: waw! I just opened that example and realized that the source code added a "new JCheckbox" to the CellEditor.
But actually it rendered as JButton. Anyway, my question is, why should we put JCheckBox into it? :(

Comment: @Bostone - How can I send the data in a different cell as parameter to the a function triggered by the button? --- The example only shows the cell's own data being used, so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: This doesn't seem to display the button click animation for me.

Comment: @ThomasAhle i'm also facing the some problem. got any solution?

Answer (score 21):

You can add Component as a table cell.

First of all, you should implement a class that has `JButton` as its parent class and two interfaces: `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor`.

The reason that it should implement `TableCellEditor` is for receiving button's `ActionEvent`.

```java
    public class TableButton extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {
      private int selectedRow;
      private int selectedColumn;
      Vector<TableButtonListener> listener;
    
      public TableButton(String text) {
        super(text); 
        listener = new Vector<TableButtonListener>();
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
            for(TableButtonListener l : listener) { 
              l.tableButtonClicked(selectedRow, selectedColumn);
            }
          }
        });
      }
     
      public void addTableButtonListener( TableButtonListener l ) {
        listener.add(l);
      }
    
      public void removeTableButtonListener( TableButtonListener l ) { 
        listener.remove(l);
      }
    
      @Override 
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        return this;
      }
    
      @Override
      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
          Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int col) {
        selectedRow = row;
        selectedColumn = col;
        return this;
      } 
    
      @Override
      public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {      
      } 
    
      @Override
      public void cancelCellEditing() {
      } 
    
      @Override
      public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return "";
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject arg0) {
        return true;
      }
    
      @Override
      public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject arg0) {
        return true;
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Then I added an `EventListener named` TableButtonListener` for handling button event as follows.

```java
    public interface TableButtonListener extends EventListener {
      public void tableButtonClicked( int row, int col );
    }
```

And use above Renderer/Editor.

```java
    TableButton buttonEditor = new TableButton("Button");
    buttonEditor.addButtonListener(new TableButtonListener() {
      @Override
      public void tableButtonClicked(int row, int col) {
        // do something 
      }     
    }); 
     
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(1, 80);
    col.setCellRenderer(buttonEditor);
    col.setCellEditor(buttonEditor);

    cols.addColumn(colPattern);
```

If you want to display different buttons label for each row, you should insert a code block into the `getTableCellRendererComponent` and `getTableCellEditorComponent` methods to modify button's label.

Comment: -1 this is an illegal implementation of CellEditor: by contract, it _must_ notify registered CellEditorListeners. Which it trivially cant with empty implementation of the addEditorListener ;-) Super contracts _must_ be served by implementations, no way around.

Comment: If you have multiple buttons in the same table, (as you will if you set this as the renderer for a column) this will have rendering issues since all the buttons are the same instance.  It does weird things like fail to draw part of the button, just draw a white background, or draw several buttons as being highlighted instead of just one.  I fixed the problem by separating to two separate classes TableButton and TableButtonEditor.  I track multiple buttons in a hashmap based on the row and column index.

Comment: just wanna say I love you. working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Table Button Column](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=table-button-column).

It demonstrates how to use a JButton as a custom renderer and editor that you can click an easily invoke an `Action`.