# What are the disadvantages in using a JButton & Action in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, listener

I have a `JTable` with custom renderers. When an item in the `JTable` is clicked, I perform a specific set of actions that affect my model. I have two choices to implement this:

**ListSelectionListener**
: I add a listener on my entire `JTable` which fires when a row is clicked. Then I perform the actions.

- Advantages: Allows me to select any part of the row (not required in my case), probably the way Swing *intended* for events to be fire in a `JTable`
- Disadvantages: I have to create a custom class to handle this and reproduce code.

Example:

```
class Selector implements ListSelectionListener {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        // ... write the action code here
    }
}
```

**JButton & Action**
: I render a `JButton` and add an `Action` to that `JButton`.

- Advantages: I can reuse that `Action`, and if I change that `Action`, all instances using it will be updated.
- Disadvantages: I move logic into my rendering code.

Example:

```
class Renderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(value.toString());
        btn.setAction(new SpecificAction());
        return btn;
    }
}
```

1. If I use the second solution, will fire rain down from the heavens?
2. Are they both equally viable?
3. Is there some way to use `Action`s inside a `ListSelectionListener`?

Comment: Have you considered creating a CellEditor instead to execute the code?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I didn't mention the CellEditor, but you're correct, Option 2 requires implementation of a CellEditor to actually fire the Action. I've opted to add an anonymous ListSelectionListener and manually create/fire the Action myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowledge of your specific use-case, here are my thoughts:

1) I wouldn't use a ListSelectionListener. Some users tend to scroll through the table via the arrow keys. I wouldn't want my listener to fire just because the user is "scrolling" with the arrow keys.  However, I have used this for some specific, less-ordinary situations.

2) I would use a renderer to display a JButton in the cell, and then add a MouseListener on the table. Convert the coordinates from the mouseClicked event to a table cell. If the cell has a ButtonRenderer, then fire the appropriate code.  This is more likely to filter out unwanted actions since clicking a specific cell is more likely to be an intentional action from the user.

EDIT:

Here's a solution from Rob Camick's site: [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

And a short discussion about it here: [Adding button to JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321623/adding-button-to-jtable)

Comment: Your (1) is a great point. However, for (2), wouldn't it be better to just set a listener on the button itself instead of manually converting for mouse clicks?

Comment: Possibly and/or probably. I'd have to think about it some more.