# How do I write an action to a check box in a table cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, tablecelleditor

In my java code, I have a table with 3 rows and 7 cells. These all rows has check boxes. Can I write an action for each check box. Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Impossible is nothing :)

Comment: Use row index you can achieve this

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475543/how-to-add-button-in-a-row-of-jtable-in-swing-java

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), `Boolean` values in your `TableModel` are "rendered with a check box." There's no need for an action listener; the default editor will handle mouse and keyboard events. Numerous examples may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:230513%20%5Bjtable%5D%20jcheckbox), [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513)

[image]