# Add Many JButtons only in one cell of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I want to use two buttons with actionperformed in only one cell of jtable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `JTable` doesn’t support a button renderer or editor.

To do this on your own:

Create a class that is both a renderer and an editor. The result is the `ButtonColumn` class. You store text (or an Icon) in the `TableModel` (the same way you store data for any other column) and the `ButtonColumn` will render the text (or the Icon) on a button. When you create the class you specify an Action that is to be invoked when the button is pressed. You also specify the column that is used to contain the button so that the renderer and editor can be automatically installed on the appropriate `TableColumn` of the `TableColumnModel`.

After adding buttons in to cell. You can easily add `ActionListenr` to buttons.

[try this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475543/how-to-add-button-in-a-row-of-jtable-in-swing-java)

[these are helpful](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htmhttp://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm)

[And this blogpost](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)