# Java create table with a button on the first row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a table where the first row contains 1 button, and the other rows contain multiple columns. Example picture:

[image]

How could I make this?

I've attempted the following: [add button to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475543/how-to-add-button-in-a-row-of-jtable-in-swing-java) but that only allows you to add a button like this: [image: example 2]

I've looked at other stackOverflow posts, but those answers contain dead links, which are no help to me.

Comment: Swing? JavaFX? Your own attempt to far?

Comment: @notyou sorry, added the swing tag. my own attempt is based on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475543/how-to-add-button-in-a-row-of-jtable-in-swing-java
however, that only allows you to add button to a cell instead of an entire row

Comment: @AndrewThompson this is exactly what i needed, please write this in an answer so i can give you credit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy by placing the button **outside** the table. Here is how to go about it:

Create a panel with a `BorderLayout`. Add the table (to a scroll pane) to the `CENTER` of the border layout. Add the button to the `PAGE_START` of the border layout. Job done.